# Eclipse RCP Plugin does not work outside Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins, load, export, rcp

I am learning the basics of E4 RCP development. I followed the tutorial below to create a basic application and a plugin.
http://www.rcp-vision.com/?p=4972&lang=en

The plugin is included in the dependencies of the **.product** file.
When I right-click the **.product** file and run as eclipse application, I can see the application and the plugin, which just adds a new menu item labelled "plugin" to the application.

But when I export the application using Eclipse Product Export Wizard, the exported eclipse.exe only launches the main rcp application without the plugin (because the "plugin" menu item is not present in the GUI). The plugin is available as a **.jar** file in the plugins folder and it is also included in the **osgi.bundles** section of the **config.ini** file.

Why is the exported application not able to find the plugin?

Comment: If your plugin is using a fragment.e4xmi check that it is included in the build.properties. When you run within Eclipse everything is available, when you export a RCP only things listed in the build.properties are available.

Comment: @greg-449 That fixed it! Thank you so much. Please post it as an answer so that I can accept it as the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to include the `fragment.e4xmi` file in the `build.properties` file.

When you run within Eclipse everything in the plugin project is available, but when you export a RCP only things listed in the build.properties are available.